# document.createElement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a plugin using jQuery library.

Here i am storing **String.prototype** in a variable then i am using this variable to extend my Sting object. And this is working fine.

```
// String Prototyping store in a variable
// Save bytes in the minified version of js
var StrProto = String.prototype;
String.prototype.toProperCase = function () {
  return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
};
// working fine
alert("yogesh kumar".toProperCase());
```

In the next case i am creating m **function xyz** which stored in
**abc** variable and this is also working fine.

```
function xyz(x){
  alert(x)
}
var abc = xyz;
// working fine
abc("yogesh kumar");
```

In the last case i am storing **document.createElement** in a variable
**tag** and using tag to create a button. but this is not working.

```
var tag=document.createElement;
$(document.createElement("button")).html("document.Element").appendTo("#myDiv");

// not working
$(tag("button")).html("tag").appendTo("#myDiv");
```

Please check the link on jsFiddle:

> [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/yoku2010/hA2pJ/)

**Error:**

*In Chrome*

- Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

*in Firefox*

- Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript
  argument

**Why this error?**

**What is the solution?**

Comment: My guess would be it loses it's context when called that way. For example, `tag.call(document,"button")` works. http://jsfiddle.net/hA2pJ/5/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting a reference to a function that is a member of the document. When you call that reference directly, it's context is now the window rather than the document. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DeCNx/

```
var foo = {
  createElement: function(tagname) {
    if (this._secretvarthatisneeded) {
      console.log(tagname + " Element Created!");
    }
  },
  _secretvarthatisneeded: true
}

foo.createElement("FOOBAR"); // works

var bar = foo.createElement;
bar("BARFOO"); // doesn't work
bar.call(foo,"BARBAR") // works
```

Since the context was lost, the `bar()` call didn't result in a `console.log();`

obviously this is just a simplification to demonstrate.

Update: For the use you are making, i'd suggest doing this:

```
$.createElement = function(tagName,attributes){
    return $(
        document.createElement(tagName),
        attributes ? attributes : {}
    )
}
```

Now you can simply do `$.createElement("button").html("tag").appendTo("#myDiv");` It is fast and still easy to read. Note however IE has problems with inputs, if you're creating input elements, i suggest using `$("<input type='text' />")` rather than this.

Comment: This is the perfect answer of my question... Thanks Kevin B.

Comment: your example is great... explanation is superb... thanks one again... i will take care of IE issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method for "assigning" the native JS method to a variable:

```
var ce = document.createElement.bind(document);
var elem = ce('div');
alert(elem.nodeName);
```

Works in modern browsers including IE9+. For older browsers, use a wrapper function.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery can [create new elements](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for you as simple as:

```
$("<button />").html("document.Element").appendTo("#myDiv");
```

To have a reason why your approach is not working, read [@Kevin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202699/document-createelement-not-working/#comment19692498_14202716) below.

Comment: my Question is why i can't store document.createElement in a javascript veriable

Comment: @yoku2010 You can, however, since it is no longer being called as a member of `document`, it's `this` (or context) is no longer the document. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hA2pJ/5/ David's answer would be a more proper way of wrapping the `document.createElement` method.

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because `document.createElement` uses `this` inside itself.  When you call it like `document.createElement()` then `this` is set to `document`.  But, when you save it as a variable, then `this` is no longer `document`, it's `window`.

You need to call it with the context.

```
var tag = document.createElement;  // you are saving the function, not its context
var btn = tag.call(document, 'button'); // you need to set the context
```

If your browser supports it, you can also use `.bind`:

```
var tag = document.createElement.bind(document);
var btn = tag('button');
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is that the method lost its context.  The method `createElement()` must be called in the context of a `document` object.

Try this in a console:

```
var tag = document.createElement;
tag.call(document, "div");  // no error
tag("div");  // error
```

The specific details of why `createElement()` must be called in the context of `document` are implementation specific, but can easily be guessed at.

So, to maintain context, create a function wrapper for `document.createElement()`:

```
function tag(tagName) {
    return document.createElement(tagName);
}
```

Of course, jQuery will also create elements for you:

```
$("<div>");  // new div element
```

Comment: $(document.createElement('div')) is faster then $('<div>') and $('<div></div>').

please check this:

http://jsperf.com/document-createelement-vs-jquery-html-string