# document.createElement illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I was thinking to minimize some javascript code but I get this "illegal invocation" error when I try to call a function through an alias

```
var d = document.createElement;
d('input');
```

Does anybody know why? tx

Comment: possible duplicate of [document.createElement not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202699/document-createelement-not-working)

Comment: try `var d = document.createElement.bind(document);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this has been addressed by others. It boils down to the fact that

`document.createElement` checks to make sure that `this` refers to `document`. You can bypass this behavior by doing the following:

Either A: always use it as `document.createElement(tagname)` OR

B

```
var o = document.createElement
o.call(document, tagname)
```

C

```
var d = document.createElement.bind(document);
```

(from above answer)

See http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/hook-document-createelement.html

Answer (score 5):

use

```
var d = document.createElement.bind(document);
```

to bind the `this` in your `d` function to the `document` object